# How to change labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have a graph:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
p
```

[image]

How to change x labels as, for example, "set", "ver" and "virg"?
I don't want to change original data.

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("setosa", "versicolor", "viginica"), labels = c("set", "ver", "virg"))` to `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `scale_x_discrete` and just adapt the `labels`:

```
p + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("set", "ver", "virg"))
```

However, you have to pay attention to the order. To avoid problems you can also add the original factor levels in `breaks` as in @Z.Lin's comment:

```
p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("setosa", "versicolor", "viginica"), 
                     labels = c("set", "ver", "virg"))
```